# C# - Block master-thread until slave-thread executed ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've a question regarding thread handling in C#:

I have a master thread who creates a slave thread with

```
pollthread = new Thread(doPollThread);
pollthread.Start(this);
```

I have a

```
ManualResetEvent resetevent
```

the slave thread executes an endless loop like

```
private static void doPollThread(object thisObject){

    SpeedCounterDevice sc = (SpeedCounterDevice) thisObject;
    while (true) {

        sc.resetevent.WaitOne();

        //do some work ....

        Thread.Sleep(400);

    }
}
```

The purpose of the slave thread is to poll an external device through a network socket (how are you .. how are you ... get measurement result ... how are you ....)
but this socket is created in functions of the master thread
And I want to connect the socket through an UI-Button-Press, disconnect through the UI, connect again, .... in the master thread
So control of the socket should belong to the master thread, only the actual data transfer over the network should be done by the slave

Now I want to suspend the slave thread in a function running in the master thread like

```
resetevent.Reset();
```

to disconnect the network connection later on when the slave loop is finished

But then I want to wait in the master thread (block it) until the slave thread executed WaitOne(), but without any possibility to come into a deadlock or something else problematic ...
(I want to finish the loop without interrupt it)

Yes, you can create another ResetEvent, block the master thread, but if the slave is getting the resetEvent right between signalling the master thread and executing WaitOne(), he will sleep but will not wake up the master thread ...

Is there any safe nice way to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Regards, Hans Juergen

Comment: Why do you have he sleep?  Put a IF statement around the WaitOne with a variable Continuous so you do not have to Wait.

Comment: Sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why does the master thread have to wait till WaitOne is executed?

Comment: It doesn't at all solve the problem, you've now got a hung thread that cannot continue because the socket is gone.  Just don't, simply have the main thread close the socket.  The worker thread now gets an ObjectDisposedException, easy to catch and reliably tells it to break out of the loop and stop running.  Also note that 400 msec is long enough to consider a timer instead.

Answer (score 0):

to wait for slave completion use `pollthread.join()`

Comment: That's it!
Closing the thread
Joining it
then closing the socket

Later on .. open the socket ones more and restart the Thread!!

Thank you very much!

Sorry, thought far too complicated! ;-)